# LUIS chatbot integration with Power BI

Tags: powerbi, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

Is there any way to get the graph from Power BI through API call? I find that there is embed URL returned by Power BI API call, but is there any way to send this embed URL and show the graph or report in chatbot (Skype or teams)?

Comment: I know using Teams bot you can post url of your report/dashboard from power bi.
But Power Bi Embed url needs a container to show the report and this container is not available I belie. But I saw some sample Bots for Team like Sky-scanner where they show flight information like card. May be you can have some feature in your chat bot which can hold (contain) embed url and show as report.

Comment: did you managed to look into it?

Comment: No, still I am searching a way to do it as Microsoft bot framework chat window doesn't support Html so I can't embed containers like an iframe. Also, it has cards classes to enrich UI but it doesn't give an embedded URL option. Currently, it will show image or videos link.

Comment: Yes, As mentioned you need container to hold Iframe and Chatbots both for Teams and Skype does not provide this functionality. I would say for now it is not possible.

Comment: do you any other way by which i can show charts and graph reports in bot chat window based on my DB data?

Comment: No the best I can suggest is get the link of your Chart/Report, post in Teams Channel and let user click it. Once user click it, they will be redirected to PowerBi Report and based on your configurations they will see the chart/report. Does that sound like a way for you?

Comment: I already know this alternative but i am looking for some way through which I can show a chart within chat window. Thanks  @AnkUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options available to you, but each is limited in different ways. All are imperfect given your specific request (i.e. chart displayed in chat). You will need to decide which is best for you.

**1) Send an adaptive card (or hero card) that contains a clickable link (via your bot)** - This will open a separate tab/window displaying the linked content. The below includes an icon image next to the link, but you could include a full image indicating the graph/report. You can experiment with designing adaptive cards [here](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/).

```js
async sendCardStep (stepContext) {
    const adaptiveCard = {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Power BI Report",
                "size": "Large"
            },
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Description of the report..."
            },
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": "stretch",
                                "minHeight": "200px",
                                "id": "column1",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Image",
                                        "altText": "",
                                        "url": "<<some link>>",
                                        "height": "200px",
                                        "width": "20px"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": "stretch",
                                "selectAction": {
                                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                                    "id": "powerBIAction",
                                    "title": "Click to Open",
                                    "url": "<<some link>>"
                                },
                                "id": "colum2",
                                "style": "default",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "ActionSet",
                                        "actions": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                                                "title": "Click to Open",
                                                "url": "<<some link>>",
                                                "id": "openUrl"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "verticalContentAlignment": "Center"
                            }
                        ],
                        "id": "columnSet",
                        "minHeight": "200px",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Left"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
    }

    const adaptiveMessage = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(adaptiveCard);
    await context.sendActivity({attachments:[adaptiveMessage]});
}
```

[image]

**2) Create a static tab (via your Teams manifest)** - This can display the linked content in the tab. However, this likely will require some level of authentication which I am lacking. Technically, this works in that the tab shows the sign-in button required to access the content. However, the sign-in button for me quickly opens and closes a browser window without allowing actual sign-in to occur for the tab. Unsure if this is specific to me or a larger issue (developer's console shows an error...may be a bug needing a proper fix). There is an open-in-browser button that, when clicked, *will* open the report in the user's browser. You can reference the custom tabs docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/design/tabs).

```js
{
  [...],
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "powerBITab",
      "name": "Power BI Report Tab",
      "contentUrl": "<<some link>>",
      "websiteUrl": "<<some link>>",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  [...]
}
```

[image]

**3) Create a task module (via your Teams manifest & bot)** - This is similar to option #1. The difference is it becomes a function of your bot and Teams and not strictly your bot. In other words, it is accessible from your bot, but in response to some action taken in Teams (vs. a waterfall step or component dialog activity sent from your bot). You can reference the task modules docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots).

```
{
  [...],
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "613ed145-a6da-4412-9435-30ac5325c84e",
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "openPowerBI",
          "type": "action",
          "context": [
            "compose"
          ],
          "description": "Command to run action to open Power BI graph",
          "title": "Open Power BI Report",
          "fetchTask": true,
          "taskInfo": {
            "title": "Card title",
            "width": "medium",
            "height": "medium",
            "url": "<<some link>>"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [...]
}
```

```js
const { TeamsActivityHandler, CardFactory, MessageFactory } = require('botbuilder');

class TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            const heroCard = this.getHeroCardMenu();
            const heroMessage = MessageFactory.attachment(heroCard);
            await context.sendActivity(heroMessage);

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });

        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const card = this.getGetHeroCardMenu();
            const message = MessageFactory.attachment(card);
            await context.sendActivity(message);

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
    };

    getHeroCardMenu() {
        return CardFactory.heroCard('Open Power BI Report',
            'Description of the report...',
            null, // No images
            [{ type: 'invoke', title: 'Click to Open', value: { type: 'task/fetch', data: 'adaptivecard' } }]);
    }

    handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch(context, taskModuleRequest) {
        // taskModuleRequest.data can be checked to determine different paths.

        return {
            task: {
                type: 'continue',
                value: {
                    card: this.getTaskModuleAdaptiveCard(),
                    height: 220,
                    width: 400,
                    title: 'Adaptive Card: Inputs'
                }
            }
        };
    }

    getTaskModuleAdaptiveCard() {
        return CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
            version: '1.0.0',
            type: 'AdaptiveCard',
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Power BI Report"
                },
                {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                            "title": "Click to Open",
                            "url": "<<some link>>",
                            "id": "powerBIAction",
                            "iconUrl": "<<some link>>"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
    }
}

module.exports.TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot = TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot;
```

[image]

**4) Create an action messaging extension (via your Teams manifest)** - This creates a modal with the report embedded within it. Presently, it suffers the same problem as the tab in that it displays the report sign-in button, but only flashes open a browser window which is immediately closed. Again, I'm unsure if this error is specific to me or not. There is no open-in-browser button option. You can reference the messaging extension docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/what-are-messaging-extensions).

```js
const { TeamsActivityHandler } = require('botbuilder');

class TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
    handleTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTask(context, action) {
        return {
            task: {
                type: 'continue',
                value: {
                    width: 500,
                    height: 450,
                    title: 'Open Power BI Report',
                    url: '<<some link>>',
                    fallbackUrl: 'https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/'
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

module.exports.TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot = TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot;
```

[image]

**App manifests** - Lastly, the app manifest will require certain properties to be included for your bot or messaging extensions to work fully with Teams. Look over the [app manifest checklist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/app-manifest-checklist), including the snippet at the bottom regarding [Submission extras for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/app-manifest-checklist#submission-extras-for-bots). Always good to reference the [manifest schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema), as well.

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks @Steven Kanberg for such a detailed answer. Approach 4 looks good to me let me try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to the problem. I am posting it here so that others can get this knowledge. 
It is right that Microsoft bot framework currently doesn't support interactive charts or embedded charts of Power BI so to show charts/graphs on bot we can use the chart APIs. Chart APIs return us chart image as a response to our request URL. Example code :

[image: Hero card code]

In result of above code I am getting output:

[image: output]

Currently, I found few Chart API service but all are paid service.

1. [QuickChart](https://quickchart.io/)
2. [ChartURL](https://charturl.com/)
3. [ImageChart](https://www.image-charts.com/)

I hope this solution helps you.